# Bind dropdown in Ultrawintree node

Tags: .net, vb.net, treeview, infragistics

I need to bind a `dropdown` in the `Ultrawintree` node. When the user double clicks the cell of the node it should be editable and so I need to show some of the values in `dropdown`. So that the user can select the values and will save/update.

//Code

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim columnSet As UltraTreeColumnSet = Me.ultraTree1.ColumnSettings.ColumnSets(0)

        '   Use the ActiveCellAppearance to bring attention to the cell
        '   with the input focus
        columnSet.ActiveCellAppearance.BackColor = Color.Red
        columnSet.ActiveCellAppearance.ForeColor = Color.White

        '   Set AllowCellEdit to 'ActivateOnly' so that clicking a cell does
        '   not put in into edit mode immediately
        columnSet.AllowCellEdit = AllowCellEdit.Full

        '   Enable tooltips for cells whose value is not fully visible
        columnSet.TipStyleCell = TipStyleCell.Show
    End Sub
```

So here when the button click happens the cell is completely editable. But instead of that I need to bind a `dropdown` in the cell. Is that possible?

How can I do that?

**Note**: I'm using the Infragistics version **12.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches to solve this task. You could try to use EditorComponent proeprty of UltraTree`s nodes. By this way you could assign a UltraComboEditor control to the nodes, which will display your dropdown values. For example:

```
this.ultraTree1.Override.ShowEditorButtons = ShowEditorButtons.Always;
        this.ultraTree1.Override.LabelEdit = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
        this.ultraTree1.Override.UseEditor = DefaultableBoolean.True;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Tabl");
        dt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(Boolean));
        dt.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(String));
        dt.Rows.Add(true, "Test A");
        dt.Rows.Add(false, "Test B");
        dt.Rows.Add(false, "Test C");
        dt.Rows.Add(true, "Test D");

        ultraCombo1.DataSource = dt;
        ultraCombo1.DisplayMember = "Y";
        ultraCombo1.ValueMember = "Y";
        this.ultraTree1.NodeLevelOverrides[0].EditorComponent = ultraCombo1;
```

More complicate and maybe more interesting approach could be if you are using UltraControlContainerEditor. Here is small sample where we implement a Grid in the UltraTree`s nodes. For example:

```
this.ultraTree1.Override.ShowEditorButtons = ShowEditorButtons.Always;
        this.ultraTree1.Override.LabelEdit = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
        this.ultraTree1.Override.UseEditor = DefaultableBoolean.True;


        UltraControlContainerEditor ucc = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraControlContainerEditor();
        UltraGrid uc = new UltraGrid();
        UltraGrid uc2 = new UltraGrid();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Tabl");
        dt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(Boolean));
        dt.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(String));
        dt.Rows.Add(true, "Test A");
        dt.Rows.Add(false, "Test B");
        dt.Rows.Add(false, "Test C");
        dt.Rows.Add(true, "Test D");

        uc2.DataSource = dt;
        uc.DataSource = dt;

        ucc.RenderingControl = uc2;
        ucc.EditingControl = uc;
        this.ultraTree1.NodeLevelOverrides[1].EditorComponent = ucc;
```

Please take a look at the screenshots to see the results

[image]